# Help me!! Extract partition table GPT

Tags: partitioning, gpt

English is not my native language, so I apologize.

I want to remove the partition table from my hard drive /dev/sdb and then put it on my disk /dev/sda, but when running the following command:

```
sudo sfdisk -d /dev/sdb | sed s/sdb/sdc/ > part.sdb
```

I get this error:

```
AVISO: ¡GPT (Tabla de partición GUID) detectada en «/dev/sdb»! La utilidad sfdisk no soporta GPT. Use GNU Parted.
```

ERROR, LITERAL TRANSLATION (real error in english could be very different)

```
WARNING: GPT (GUID partition table) detected on /dev/sdb!. sfidk utility doesn't support GTP, please use GNU Parted.
```

I have little linux knowledge, but by reading little by little I'm improving.

Can you help?

Thank you very much!

---

Hola,

MI ingles no es mi lengua materna, por eso me disculpo.

Deseo Extraer la tabla de particiones de mi disco duro /deb/sdb y luego colocar esta en mi disco /deb/sda, pero al realizar el comando siguiente:

sudo sfdisk -d /dev/sdb | sed s/sdb/sdc/ > part.sdb

AVISO: ¡GPT (Tabla de partición GUID) detectada en «/dev/sdb»! La utilidad sfdisk no soporta GPT. Use GNU Parted.

No puedo realizarla.

MIs conocimientos de linux son pocos, pero leyendo poco a poco he podido.

Me pueden Colaborar?

Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Were you ever able to accomplish whatever it is you were trying to accomplish? (Were you just trying to display/list the contents of the GPT on `/dev/sdb`?)

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, you should be able to perform what you want with `gdisk` (you may need to install it first):

- Start with `sudo gdisk /dev/sdb`
- Choose option `b` for backup and when prompted for filename, type `sdb.part` (or whatever you want)
- Choose option `q` for quit
- Restart gdisk with the drive to be overwritten: `sudo gdisk /dev/sda`
- **Double check** that you entered the correct device, next commands will overwrite its partition table
- Choose option `r` for recovery
- Choose option `l` to load partition table from file, type `sdb.part` (the name you used with the above backup command)
- Choose option `w` to write the partition table (it will verify you really want to do this)

Now, as I mentioned in the beginning, this is how it is supposed to work in theory. In practice, there are three caveats:

- `gdisk` is beta software (even the latest 0.8.2 version)
- Versions of `gdisk` available in released ubuntu versions are really old: lucid has 0.5.1 and oneiric has 0.6.14. If at all possible, use precise as it has 0.8.1, which is recent, or download latest from [gdisk download page](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/download.html).
- Above instructions may contain mistakes and seriously corrupt your disks! I have not verified they work as intended!

If you decide to go forward despite these warnings: buena suerte y ten mucho cuidado!

Comment: It can actually be done a bit more easily than this: Starting from the disk whose partition table you want to duplicate, you can type `x` to get to the experts' menu and then type `u` to replicate the partition table on another device. You'll need to then enter that device's name. Doing it as you suggested has the advantage, though, that you can double-check the status of the target disk before overwriting its contents.